# Notify cursor of one table on changes in another table

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-contentprovider

Suppose I have CursorLoader listening for changes in table1 addressed with CONTENT_URI_1.
The data in table1 depends on contents of table2 addressed with CONTENT_URI_2 (For those who interested in details, table1 is sql view over table2).

Any loaders are notified of changes of tables contents via setNotificationUri() in my content provider.

Now, from some other spot I'm inserting a row into table2, which sends notifications of CONTENT_URI_2 changes. But CONTENT_URI_1 is not being notified, because there could be only one notification uri per cursor.

The question is how can I notify CONTENT_URI_1 when CONTENT_URI_2 changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer shortly after posting the question :)

If you want to notify CONTENT_URI_1 (table1) after, for instance, inserting data into CONTENT_URI_2 (table2), you should do the following:

```
Uri resultUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI_2, table2rowDataContentValues);
// simply notify whatever URI you desire of changes
context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_1, null);
```

Pretty straightforward but didn't come to me at first.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `ContentObserver` in your Activity/Fragment:

Register it in your `onResume()`  and deregister it in your `onPause`.

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CONTENT_URI2, true, yourObserver);
```

Follow this [link](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/). When your `onChange()` callback is called in your `ContentObserver` call to your `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in order to refresh your `ListView`

Hope it helps

Comment: This could be if I wasn't using CursorLoader. I wanted to use its native notifications capabilities. Nevertheless I found the answer myself, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question but still relevant enough to update with a new answer.

If you have a uri pointing to a table, and one uri pointing to a view of the table, then we could automatically notify the view when the table is changed by just using the correct naming of the uirs.

Lets name the uri to the table, the CONTENT_URI_2 in the querstion, to

```
content://authority/table1
```

And then if we name the viewing uri to

```
content://autority/table1/view1
```

Then any changes to the table using `content://authority/table1` will automatically notify `content://authority/table1/view1`

Comment: Nice idea, will check this another day